# Webpage archiver using http-requests/responses replay

Tags: windows, download-manager, web, http, archiving

I'm looking for a Webpage Archiver that depends on archiving a webpage by recording http requests and responses and just replaying them when the webpage archive is previewed/loaded by the user.

It's preferable to work the *http-replay* way because it's more efficient than *remapping the files* and downloading them, because most of the software that work by remapping files fail with many webpages and doesn't display them correctly as they are specially when it hits complicated JavaScript or other complicated dependencies. I think that working by the http-requests-way guarantees 100% that the page will be reloaded/viewed completely as the user viewed it when he/she was online because just the requests made are being replayed and no chance that anything will be messed up with any type of content.

I really prefer some HAR file viewer that executes the first request/response and replay all subsequent requests/responses to preview the archived page.

---

Preferences:
Operating system: supports Windows 10
Price: Any
Preferably Open Source
If a browser addon, I prefer Chrome.

Comment: And you want that for what OS? Plus you are aware that with replay this isn't really archiving, and parts might get broken when pages go offline (or I didn't understand correctly what you've meant by replay instead of remap)? Also, any price limit when it comes to paid software?

Comment: I've added them. In Chrome Network analyzer, selecting *disable cache* & *Preserve log* & making the first webpage call, makes all important requests/responses recorded. More server-side data that needs manual user interaction with elements that calls the server for them (we may use some programming that detects all these elements and hit them—however, it's hard to decide whether an element calls for data user need to store offline or calls unexpected action without manual user provision)...

Comment: …But for saving the webpage offline in a "What You see is What You Save" way, this way preserves 100% without any potential crashes (except interactions that required server response that weren't hit/called and it's very rare for the targeted webpages that I think most of the users will need to save). I think this tool will be totally efficient for single-webpage saving (not website sniffing/bulk webpages saving). We may think of it as something like "save my tab offline".

Comment: Ah, I guess I see what you mean: you rather ask about something that serves as cache inside the browser? Probably as addon? If so, does any browser suffice, or do you have preferences (your comment e.g. speaks of Chrome)?

Comment: Yes, if an addon, I prefer Chrome.